# Is there a way to intercept ALL JavaScript errors?

Tags: javascript, exception

**Goal:** When any JS error occurs, grab the information from that error and execute a custom function with it.

**Description:** If a script creates an error like this...

```
var a = test;
// VM334:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

...how can I "intercept" that error; perhaps something like this:

```
Error.onerror = function(e){ alert("The error is " + e ); } 
// "The error is VM334:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined"
```

**Note:**
I am aware of the following:

```
window.onerror = function(){...}
window.addEventListener('error', ... )
```

Unfortunately these do not get the job done for reasons I believe are related to scope. I believe many errors will fail to be tracked because they do not live on the window object.

`try{}catch(e){alert(e)}` is also not a solution because it is too particular about where the errors come from.

I have also tried overwriting `console.error` but this function is not called when a JS error occurs on page.

Is there a way to respond to ANY JS error?

Cheers

Comment: Certain kinds of errors cannot be caught by your javascript. For example, syntax errors cannot be caught by virtue of being unable to run the code to begin with.

Comment: If errors are caught, you are not going to get them.